# Sent Email process not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a question about my application built in Oracle APEX 4.2. This application has a process to send emails (when a user changes his password or requests a password reset).

When I run this application online on my "apex.oracle.com" account, it runs fine. But when I run it on my home computer (running Windows 7), the email process doesn't work. Probably it is because my home server is not an email server.

Can someone please help me so that my home computer is able to send emails via my above mentioned application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have several options:

1. Configure a local SMTP server so it can be use by APEX and send emails.
2. Connect to a remote server - like Google - and sends emails that way (you have to open a new account and connect with that and also there's some certificate problems, https://arkatec.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/sending-email-using-oracle-database-and-google-mail-service/)
3. Use htmldb_mail package (I haven't tried this one)

In the first options you need to construct a procedure that does all the work for you.

You can use one of this:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL

Important: keep in my that you're going to encounter permission issues with the UTL packages (grant execute on UTL_XXX to USER) and algo, if you're are working on 11g you need to create an ACL